# Cursor equivalent for Gemfire?

Tags: java, gemfire, geode

I use Gemfire 8.x and I have a Gemfire region where there are many objects in it (let's say there are billions of them) and I need to write some Java code which does some kind of bulk processing with a huge result set from the region.

If it was a traditional RDBMS, I would use a cursor for that so that I won't get an OutOfMemoryError. Is there an equivalent in Gemfire? Or do I have to implement some kind of custom paging logic with the `LIMIT` keyword in OQL for implementing this kind of bulk processing with a large result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `CURSOR` equivalent in `GemFire`, you need to retrieve the results using `LIMIT` instead. As a side note, it would be beneficial (and probably better) to write a custom [Function](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/910/geode/developing/function_exec/chapter_overview.html) instead of using `OQL` from a client application, that will allow you to process the data in place and prevent the whole data set from moving to the client side.

Cheers.